# How to throw file extension exception in the File Dialog window?

Tags: c#, file

I writing code to upload pdf file onto the third party server. I have done some path validation checks. I am checking if the file exists or not. Now for this validation the c# automatically throws an exception message box, without closing file dialog(browser window). I want to implement same validation for file extension. I tried checking for extension and then throwing the exception in message box, but the file dialog closes. I am attaching a screen shot so that this becomes clearer. 
[This type of validation I want and the background window should remain open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tyIC.png)

This validation I want to implement for file extension. As far as I know there are not exceptions for validating file extensions.

```
public System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog cmndBrowseOpen;
public System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog cmndBrowseSave;
public System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult cmdBrowseResult
public void cmdBrowse_Click()
    {
        const string sFilter = "PDFs (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
        string sMsg = String.Empty;
        string sTitle = String.Empty;
        FileInfo oFile = null;

        try
        {
            if (moFrmIntComplaint != null)
            {
                moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.Filter = sFilter;
                moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.Title = ResourceHandler.Resources.GetString("BrowseFile:Title");
                moFrmIntComplaint.cmdBrowseResult = moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.ShowDialog();
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileName);
                moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.DefaultExt = ".pdf";

                if (fileExtension != ".pdf")
                {
                    moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileOk += delegate(object s, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs ev)
                    {

                        ev.Cancel = true;

                    };
                }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileName) == false)
                    {
                        oFile = new FileInfo(moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileName);

                        if ((oFile != null) && (File.Exists(moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileName) && (fileExtension == ".pdf")))
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToDouble(oFile.Length) > dMaxFileSize)
                            {
                                sTitle = ResourceHandler.Resources.GetString("BrowseFile:FilSizTitle");
                                sMsg = ResourceHandler.Resources.GetString("BrowseFile:FileSize");
                                Cerner.Foundations.Measurement.TimedMessageBox.Show(sMsg, sTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                                moFrmIntComplaint.lblFileName.Text = System.String.Empty;
                                moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text = System.String.Empty;
                                moFrmIntComplaint.cmdRemove.Visible = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                        moFrmIntComplaint.lblFileName.Text = Path.GetFileName(moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileName);
                                        moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text = moFrmIntComplaint.cmndBrowseOpen.FileName;
                                        moFrmIntComplaint.cmdRemove.Left = moFrmIntComplaint.lblFileName.Left + moFrmIntComplaint.lblFileName.Width + 5;
                                        moFrmIntComplaint.cmdRemove.Visible = true;

                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            return;
        }
```

The top three statements are in a different class called moFrmIntComplaint. As these variables are used in the browse_click method, this why I have mentioned these variables here. I have tried using delegate [because of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766216/keep-openning-openfiledialog-until-selecting-valid-file?answertab=active#tab-top)
Even this doesn't help.

Comment: It doesn't "Throw exception message box" it actaully handle exception by showing message box. If You throw exception in some point it will dive to the top until it will be handled.

Comment: Yes C# handles the exception and gives appropriate message if the file exists or not. I want to know how to implement similar kind of handling for extensions. specifically I want the back ground window(file dialog) to be open when the error message comes.

Comment: Paste Your code and we will take a look.

Comment: Shouldn't you just do all that validation in the `FileOk` handler? It's very unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You can validate in 'FileOk' , but still over there also there are no exceptions for file extensions.